# REST API calls for setting namespace preferences and Program preferences

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

Can the namespace preferences and program preferences be set via REST API calls? If yes, what is the syntax for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in Cloud Data Fusion, when we intend to perform the action on GCP side, like *create/delete/restart* etc. instance, it's feasible to use domestic [Google Cloud API](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/overview), giving the opportunity to interact with a service endpoint via JSON/HTTP calls interface as described in Google Cloud API [design](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design) document.

Dedicated to Data Fusion you can follow the [Cloud Data Fusion REST API](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/rest) reference document, nicely explaining the methods for composing REST API HTTP calls to manage Data Fusion instances, moreover every method description from the documentation contains [Google API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/apis-explorer) sub-panel, to get handy experience building JSON request on a live data.

Said above, I assume your initial question is related more to [CDAP REST API](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/477593807/CDAP+HTTP+RESTful+API+v3), as it includes the methods for pure CDAP instance *metadata/namespaces/application* configuration.

From the user perspective your workflow might be the following:

- Identify the CDAP API endpoint as explained in this [guideline](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference);
- Compose an HTTP PUT/GET request relevant to Data Fusion
  [Namespace](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/477561041/Namespace+HTTP+RESTful+API)/[Metadata](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/477692187/Metadata+HTTP+RESTful+API)/[Preferences](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/477561058/Preferences+HTTP+RESTful+API)/[Configuration](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/477692155/Configuration+HTTP+RESTful+API)
  object via CDAP RESTful API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course! You have two methods.

The first method is creating it from the platform. Follow the steps below:

1. Open your data fusion instance
2. Go to System Admin => Configuration => Make HTTP calls
3. To create a namespace, submit an HTTP PUT request:
   `PUT /v3/namespaces/<namespace-id>`

Link of CDAP: [CDAP](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/477561041/Namespace+Microservices#Create-a-Namespace)

The second method is using terraform.